# Exit loop at the end of current iteration step if condition is fulfilled

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, octave

A common problem I have is the following:

Within a loop (usually a for loop) some **constraints are** - and have to be - **checked at the beginning**. Now sometimes if a condition if fulfilled, the code within the loop should run **to the end of the current iteration step and then quit**.

Usually I'd do it somehow like so

```
a = 0;
quit = 0;

for i = 1:1:11
  if (a == 5)    % Condition to be checked *before* the calculation
    quit = 1;    % Stop loop after this iteration
  end

  a = a + 1;     % Calculation
  ...

  if (quit == 1)
    break;
  end
end
```

But in a tight loop already this extra condition checking `if (quit == 1)` might give a relevant slow down. Also one needs to introduce an extra variable so I wonder how this is usually done or if there is a better way to do it...

Comment: you can skip one if statement and the quit variable if you save the value of a at the start of every iteration in a temp-variable.

Comment: Please show an exmaple where the condition to be checked is a relevant slow-down? Otherwise use a while loop, the JIT compiler will probably optimize that for you in that case.

Comment: @EJG89 for simple cases the JIT _might_ optimize the `for` loop. For more elaborated cases, that's not the case. Just imagine that variable `a` comes from a function that reads a value from a file and returns it. Or if `a` comes from a function that generates a value from a random distribution and returns it.

Comment: Well, `quit` is a `logical` variable really thus the overhad of checking if `quit` is `true` or `false` is negligible. If you really care then move the condition checking to the end of the loop and exit immediately without assigning `quit = 1`. That's all you can do.

Comment: I have removed my reply as it was incorrect, as pointed out by PertH.

Comment: @gire Yes it might, if it cannot the code is too complex meaning that the check is negligible anyway

Answer (score 0):

why not do this way.

```
for i = 1:1:11
  if (a == 5)    % Condition to be checked *before* the calculation
    func()  --> do all the calculations
    break;    % Stop loop after this iteration
  else 
    func()   --> do all calculations
  end
end

function func()
 a = a+1
 //all other calculations
end
```

Comment: Would I need to pass the variables (`a` and so on) to the function, if its in the same file, i. e. does each function has it's own scope?

Comment: not necessary. a will be global in the case i have written. You can also pass a copy.. up to u..

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can detect when to stop iterating. But if I understand your question, you can only detect when it should be the last iteration. You could try this:

```
a = 0;
i = 1;
while (i<=11)
    if (a == 5)
        i = 12;    % Make sure this is the last iteration
    else
        i = i + 1;
    end

    a = a + 1;
end
```

Comment: You should use ii instead of i to avoid the removal of the standard complex number i

Comment: I agree it is preferable. It's just that, for clarity, I prefer to make the minimal changes that answer the question (hence I kept the same variable names).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for i = 1:11
    quit = (a==5); % Condition to be checked *before* the calculation
    a = a+1
    if quit
        break;     % Stop loop after this iteration
    end
end
```

Makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
- Make an infinite loop with logical variable condition set to 1
- Within the loop when stopping loop criteria rises set the logical 
  variable condition to 0
- loop will no longer run 



count = 0;
stop = 11;
condition = 1;
while condition
      count = count + 1;
      --> do all the calculations before checking 
      condition = ~(a == 5 || count == stop);
      --> do all the remaining calculations then exit from the loop      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Answering Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). You should explain why you think this is a right answer

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is enough

```
a = 0;
quit = 0;

while (a <= 5)
  a++;     % Calculation
  ...
end
```